# Manipulating shared data using mutex and semaphores

Tags: mutex, semaphore

I wanted someone to resolve my confusion on this topic. It may sound simple, but am really confused.

In producer/consumer problem, I used 4-semaphore solution. I used a different lock for each of the critical sections. 
Say,

```
Pseudo code of producer:
    wait(slot) // counting sem
       wait(mutex1) // binary sem
         rear <-- rear + 1
         buffer[rear] <-- item
       signal (mutex1)
    signal(items)
```

Where I use, "mutex2" as a second Mutex for my consumer, as "mutex1" in producer.

Now, my question is. If my producer and consumer is not using a buffer (rear and front) but using a stack, where only they can manipulate [top]. Do I need to use one mutex or two different locks as in my 4-semaphore, in order to ensure mutual exclusion.

```
 Pseudo code of consumer with stack:
         wait (message)
            wait (mutex)
              getspace <-- stack[top]
              top – 1
            signal (mutex)
          signal (slot)
```

Personally, I think I need one lock for both procedures, so I make sure none of the producer and consumer access the top concurrently. But am not sure about that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I follow your pseudo-code but I'll do my best to explain how to use semaphores to manage a stack from within the Producer-consumer process.

When you have a stack that is being accessed across multiple threads, you will need to lock it when the data is being accessed or, more specifically, when it is being pushed and popped.  (This is always an underlying assumption of the Producer-consumer problem.)

We start off by defining a mutex that we will use to lock the stack.

**Global Declaration of Process Semaphores**

```
stackAccessMutex = semaphore(1) # The "(1)" is the count 
                                # initializer for the semaphore.
```

Next, we will need to lock it when we are adding or removing data from it in our Consumer and Producer threads.

**Producer thread**

```
dataPushBuff #Buffer containing data to be pushed to the stack.

…dataPushBuff is assigned…

stackAccessMutex.wait()
    stack.push(dataPushBuff)
stackAccessMutex.signal()
```

**Consumer thread**

```
dataRecvBuff = nil # Defining a variable to store the pushed
                   # content, accessible from only within 
                   # the Consumer thread.

stackAccessMutex.wait()
    dataRecvBuff = stack.pop()
stackAccessMutex.signal()

…Consume dataRecvBuff as needed since it's removed from the stack…
```

So far, everything is pretty straight forward.  The Producer will lock the stack only when it needs to.  The same is true for the consumer.  We shouldn't need another semaphore, should we?  Correct?  No, wrong!

The above scenario makes one fatal assumption-- that the stack will always be initialized with data before it is popped.  If the consumer thread executes before the producer thread gets a chance to pop any data, you will generate an error within your consumer thread because `stack.pop()` will not return anything!  To fix this, we need to signal the consumer that data is available in the stack.

First, we need to define a semaphore that can be used to signal whether data in the stack exists or not.

**Global Declaration of Process Semaphores, Version #2**

```
stackAccessMutex = semaphore(1)
itemsInStack     = semaphore(0)
```

We initialize our `itemsInStack` to the number of items in our stack, which is 0 <sub>(see 1)</sub>.

Next, we need to implement our new semaphore into our Producer and Consumer threads.  First, we need to have the Producer signal that an item has been added.  Let's update the Producer now.

**Producer thread, Version #2**

```
dataPushBuff

…dataPushBuff is assigned…

stackAccessMutex.wait()
    stack.push(dataPushBuff)
stackAccessMutex.signal()
itemInStack.signal() #Signal the Consumer, we have data in the stack!
                     #Note, this call can be placed within the 
                     #stackAccessMutex locking block, but it doesn't 
                     #have to be there.  As a matter of convention, any
                     #code that can be executed outside of a lock, 
                     #should be executed outside of the lock.
```

Now that we can check to see if there is data in the stack via a semaphore, let's re-write our Consumer thread.

**Consumer thread, Version #2**

```
dataRecvBuff = nil # Defining a variable to store the pushed
                   # content, accessible from only within 
                   # the Consumer thread.

itemsInStack.wait()
stackAccessMutex.wait()
    dataRecvBuff = stack.pop()
stackAccessMutex.signal()

…Consume dataRecvBuff as needed since it's removed from the stack…
```

… and that's it.  As you can see, there are two semaphores and both are mandatory <sub>(see 2)</sub> because we need to lock our stack when it's accessed *and* we need to signal our consumer when data is available and lock it when there is nothing in the stack.

Hope that answered your question.  I'll update my response if you have any specific questions.

1. Theoretically, when the process starts, you could
   pre-initialize your stack with data.  In this case, you <strike>can</strike> should
   initialize your `itemsInStack` semaphore with the value that is
   equal to the stack count.  However, in the case of this example, we
   are assuming that there is no data in the stack, nor none to
   initialize.
2. It is worth mentioning that under one, specific circumstance you
   can theoretically get away with using just the `stackAccessMutex`. 
   Consider the case where the stack always contains data.  If the
   stack is infinite, we do not need to signal our Consumer that data
   has been added because there always will be data.  However, in
   reality an "infinite stack" doesn't exist.  Even if that should be
   the case within your current context, there's no overhead in adding
   the safety net of the `itemsInStack` semaphore.

   Also, it may be tempting to to throw out the `itemsInStack` counting
   semaphore if under your current circumstance a call to
   `stack.pop()` would not cause any error if it were to not return any
   data on an empty stack.

   This is plausible, but not recommended.  Assuming the Consumer thread is executing the 
   code on a loop, the loop will continuously execute the stack consumption code while
   there is no data to consume.  By using the `itemsInStack` semaphore, you are pausing the
   thread until data arrives which should save a few CPU cycles.